# Meteor didn't stop fibers execution

Tags: meteor, node-async, node-fibers

I want to upload csv file and insert it into db after huge validation and some process. I am using `fibers` for asynchronous call. But the fiber process keep executing even fiber returns `future.wait();`.

```
Meteor.methods({
  uploadCSV: (calender) {
    if (Meteor.isServer) {
      var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
      var future = new Future();
      calender = parse(calender);
      future["return"](saveCalender(calender)); //huge process and validation
      console.log(future); // { value: 1, resolved: true }
      return future.wait();
    }
  }
});
```

`saveCalender` function executes every time. Did I missed anything to stop fiber execution or how do I stop fiber execution?